# DDos attack ToS Violation - Outbound DoS

Tags: ubuntu, ddos

Fount ddos attack on ubuntu server

`netstat -nputw`

given outout

```
Local Address       Foreign Address        State        PID/Program name

55.57.72.37:59792   123.166.137.95:25000    SYN_SENT    2890/ip6tablesu.sh
```

I found on internet that `123.166.137.95` is China's ip address

How should I block outbound traffic to that address?

Comment: ip6tablesu.sh this program is running -- I think it's an maleware. How I should stop it?

Comment: The f_c_in_ Linode server got hacked with ddos attack. That's why getting Outbound traffic. aaahhhhh (angry)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/532305/using-ufw-to-block-outgoing-traffic-to-website

```
sudo ufw deny out from any to 123.166.137.95
```

As far as dealing with or cleaning up your compromised server goes, see this previously answered question:

[Detect process that is doing an outbound DDoS attack](https://serverfault.com/questions/488089/detect-process-that-is-doing-an-outbound-ddos-attack?rq=1)